# Azure Consumption Container wise

Tags: azure-storage

Can we get the consumption details of any specific container under specific blob? Like if we have 3 blobs A,B,C and each blob has 3 container. Thus A has 3 containers A1,A2 & A3 and B has 3 Containers B1,B2,B3 and C has 3 Containers C1,C2,C3
Microsoft Azure  reports provide consumption of overall subscription. Can we get the bandwidth, storage, CDN Transactions, Data transfer of Specific container wise.
Please Suggest.

Comment: Blobs are located inside containers, so this doesn't quite make sense. The top paragraph of this [how to](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) helps clarify that. Could you please rephrase the question?

Answer (score 0):

As Emily stated, blobs are under containers, and containers are under Storage accounts. If you're looking for metrics for a Storage account (e.g. E2E latency, total requests), then yes you can do that. This is all provided in the Storage Account blade on the Portal. For container specific metrics, it might be worth checking out Message Analyzer. The following article may help https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-e2e-troubleshooting/